Why should I not pass a lambda with by-reference captures to the std::thread constructor?
I wrote a timer class, but it does not work the way I needed it to. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?
template<typename D, typename C>
class timer
{
public:
    timer(D period, C&& callback)
    {
        std::thread t{[&](){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(period);
            callback();
        }};

        t.detach();
    }
};

int main()
{
    timer t1(std::chrono::seconds(2), [](){
        std::cout << "hello from 1\n";
    });

    timer t2(std::chrono::seconds(3), [](){
        std::cout << "hello from 2\n";
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}

The output is only:
hello from 1

Where is the 'hello from 2' line?

By-reference capture and asynchronous callbacks don’t mix.

why would you detach the timer thread?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai , because if does not detach it, terminate function will be called after constructor exit

@Andrey you can avoid that by making the std::thread be a member of the timer class, then join() the thread in the timer's destructor

@RemyLebeau, yes, I could, but for what? Weather will it be simpler than use just one line of code? What's the advantage?

@Andrey if you detach a thread, you lose access to it. It can be dangerous to detach a thread and have no way to stop it or wait on it if you need to. There are very few reasons to ever detach a thread. When should I use std::thread::detach?

In your constructor:

timer(D period, C&& callback)
{
    std::thread t{[&](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(period);
        callback();
    }};

    t.detach();
}


period and callback are destroyed as timer returns, and timer returns way before callback is called, and possibly even before sleep_for is called.
The fix is to copy period and callback into the thread's functor so that those copies are still alive while the thread runs:
timer(D period, C&& callback)
{
    std::thread t{[=](){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(period);
        callback();
    }};

    t.detach();
}


Another thing that should be addressed is that C&& is not a forwarding reference. Either the constructor should be turned into a template, or callback should be moved from when capturing it in the lambda expression.
